# How to calculate dsPIC internal clock (Fosc) using FRC Divide-by-N?

Tags: clock, microchip

I'm currently programming a [dspic33ep256mc506](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=dsPIC33EP256MC506) but I'm a little confused by the configuration of it.
At the moment I'm just testing the internal clock for debugging purposes, but am unsure what the maximum frequency is. All I'm trying to do is figure out how to calculate the Fosc and Fcy for Internal Fast RC (FRC) Divide-By-N  (FRCDIVN).

As far as I'm aware, the CPU speed is 70 MIPS, and supposedly 7.43 Mhz is the default Fosc.

Originally I was under the impression that FRCDIVN is based on the \$F_{PLL}\$, so something like this would set it to 4 MHz

```
/* Configure Oscillator to operate the device at 4Mhz */
// Fosc= Fin*M/(N1*N2), Fcy=Fosc/2
// M is PLLDIV + 2
PLLFBDbits.PLLDIV = 11; //M is 13
// N1 is PLLPRE + 2
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 10;  //N1 is 12
// N2 is 2*(PLLPOST + 1)
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 1; // N2 is 2
// Fosc = Fin * 43/(80) = Fin * 128; 7.37 * 43/ 80 = 4Mhz
// Fcy = Fosc / frcdiv (if 0 then 1)
CLKDIVbits.FRCDIV = 0;
```

Reading the [oscillator module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005131a.pdf) it seems like that's not the case with FRC divid-by-n (FNOSC_FRC).
[image]

So now I'm trying to use FRC divide-by-n with PLL (FNOSC_FRCPLL), and was wondering whether now the final Fosc is 4Mhz.

```
_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRCPLL);
CLKDIVBITS.FRCDIV = 0;      //FRC Divid-by-1
OSCTUNbits = 0;     //7.373Mhz

/* Configure Oscillator to operate the device at 4Mhz */
// Fosc= Fin*M/(N1*N2), Fcy=Fosc/2
// M is PLLDIV + 2
PLLFBDbits.PLLDIV = 11; //M is 13
// N1 is PLLPRE + 2
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 10;  //N1 is 12
// N2 is 2*(PLLPOST + 1)
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 1; // N2 is 2
// Fosc = Fin * 43/(80) = Fin * 128; 7.37 * 43/ 80 = 4Mhz
// Fcy = Fosc / (DOZE+1) 
CLKDIVbits.FRCDIV = 0;
CLKDIVbits.DOZE = 0;
```

**Now i'm wondering if all of this calculated correctly and noticing that extra divide block after the mux, is Fosc 4Mhz and the Fcy 2Mhz?**

p.s. suppose I were to use FRC Divide-by-N, and adjust it based on ostune register, where 0 is 7.373 Mhz. The oscillator module data sheet suggests I look at the tolerance to determine how much each bit affects the new clock. I'm not exactly sure how to find this out.

---

Here's the starting FOSC configuration generated:

```
// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow only one reconfiguration)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are disabled)


// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN          // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC) Oscillator with postscaler)
#pragma config PWMLOCK = ON             // PWM Lock Enable bit (Certain PWM registers may only be written after key sequence)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up device with FRC, then switch to user-selected oscillator source)
```

---

#### Update

So i put together an experiment to test it. I set a for loop, with led toggling delay of 3 seconds

```
for(;;){
     //__delay32(1000000);
     __delay_ms(3000);
     LED15=!LED15;
}
```

and in the beginning I included `libpic30.h` and defined

```
 #define FCY 2000000UL
 #define FOSC 4000000UL
```

although it couldn't compile to use the __ms_delay(x) defend in the libpic30.h, i copied it over to the `main.c`

```
#define __delay_ms(d) \
  { __delay32( (unsigned long) (((unsigned long long) d)*(FCY)/1000ULL)); }
#define __delay_us(d) \
  { __delay32( (unsigned long) (((unsigned long long) d)*(FCY)/1000000ULL)); }
```

using this configuration I noticed the delay with __ms_delay(3000) is actually 6 seconds, not 3 seconds.

On the second try I redefined FCY as

```
#define FCY 1000000UL
```

then the __ms_delay(3000) ended up being 3 seconds, which seems to point out that Fcy is actually 1Mhz, and the Fosc is 2Mhz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized I made a mistake when calculating the numerator of the oscillator frequency, turns out that N2 is set to 4 in this configuration because it's  `2*(PLLPOST+1)` where `PLLPOST = 1`
as oppose to what I originally thought, N2 being `(PLLPOST+1)`

So in this case Fosc = 7.37*13/(12*4) = 2Mhz, which means Fcy is half of that, 1Mhz

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but here is a code example which I made a while ago to verify FCY, __delay_ms() and _T1Interrupt. This example uses default values for the simplest clock path for dsPIC33EV.

[image]

```
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN // Internal Fast RC (FRC) with postscaler
#pragma config IESO = ON       // Start up device with FRC,then .... 
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE   // Primary Oscillator disabled

#define FCY 3685000UL // See clock_init() below.

#include <xc.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

#ifndef __dsPIC33EV256GM102__
#error "does not match processor setting"
#endif

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, auto_psv)) _T1Interrupt(void)
{
    // turn an digital output on/off here.
    IFS0bits.T1IF = 0; // Clear Timer1 interrupt flag
}

/***********************************************************************
* Prototype:
* Description:
* Arguments:
* Return:
* Detail:      
***********************************************************************/ 
void clock_init()
{
    // I did nothing here. Here are default values.
    //     Internal, 1% Fast RC (FRC) is 7.37 MHz.
    //     CLKDIVbits.FRCDIV is 000 = RFC divided by 1 (default)
    //     PLLFBDbits.DOZEN  is 0 = forced to 1:1
    // So Fosc is 7.37 Mhz and Fcy is 3.685 MHz.
}

void timer1_init()
{
    // See DS70000600D, dsPIC33/PIC24 Family Reference Manual, 5.5 Code Example
    // Set up Timer1 in 16-bit Timer mode with an interrupt on every 1 msec.
    T1CONbits.TON = 0;          // Disable Timer
    T1CONbits.TCS = 0;          // Select internal instruction cycle clock
    T1CONbits.TGATE = 0;        // Disable Gated Timer mode
    T1CONbits.TCKPS = 0b00;     // Select 1:1 Prescaler
    TMR1 = 0x0000;              // Clear timer register
    PR1 = (FCY / 1 / 1000) - 1; // Load the period value for 1 msec. 0.2% error
    IPC0bits.T1IP = 0x01;       // Set Timer1 Interrupt Priority Level
    IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;          // Clear Timer1 Interrupt Flag
    IEC0bits.T1IE = 1;          // Enable Timer1 interrupt
    T1CONbits.TON = 1;          // Start Timer
}

int main(void)
{
    clock_init();

    timer1_init();

    while (1)
    {
        ClrWdt();

        // __delay_us() and __delay_ms() depend on FCY. See libpic30.h
        __delay_us(500); // 3% error
        
        // turn an digital output on/off here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```